# Dynamically inject a type in a generic variable in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I have a dictionary like below.

```
Dictionary<string, Expression> expressions = new Dictionary<string, Expression> { 
    { "Price", (Expression<Func<Phone, double>>) (p => p.Price) },     
    { "Brand", (Expression<Func<Phone, string>>) (p => p.Name) }     
    };
```

Using entity framework, i can get result data like below.

```
BdPhonesDbEntities db = new BdPhonesDbEntities();
IQueryable<Phone> phones = db.Phones.Where(search.GetExpression());
```

Now according to the selection of the user, I want to sort this result with by price (which is double) or by name (which is string). The sorting work well with a fixed type (double) like below.

```
    Expression<Func<Phone, double>> keySelector =  
KeySelector<Func<Phone, double>>(expressions, search.OrderBy.PropertyName);
```

**Now I want to dynamically insert the type in the position of 'double' instead of fixing this only for double type sorting. is it possible to change the sorting conditionally of this code?**

To understand the total code in a single glimpse please check the below image or from [***Gist***](https://gist.github.com/foyzulkarim/8fed29730847dc6917fd)

[image]

The calling to this function is happening like below:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any reason it can't be - just add a generic argument to `Search`.

Comment: sorry Daniel. my mistake. this Search is coming from browser like a json and i am casting this with JSon.Net library. So, SearchModel shouldn't have any '<>' inside of this. I have edited the question. please check

Comment: @Foysal You can make use of [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic) to make this all auto.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Utility class https://dotnetfiddle.net/T9CFYU

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, object>> GetExpressionForProp<TSource>(this TSource source, string propertyName)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
        Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, propertyName), typeof(object));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(conversion, param);
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByProp<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName) 
        where TSource : class, new()
    {
        return source.OrderBy(new TSource().GetExpressionForProp(propertyName));

        //or comment where TSource : class, new() and
        //var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
        //Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, propertyName), typeof(object));
        //var shortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(conversion, param);
        //return source.OrderBy(shortExpression);
    }
}
```

some usage like,

```
List<Phone> orderedByPrice = null;
List<Phone> orderedByBrand = null;

/*Try: 1*/
orderedByPrice = Db.Phones.OrderBy(new Phone().GetExpressionForProp("Price")).ToList(); 
orderedByBrand = Db.Phones.OrderBy(new Phone().GetExpressionForProp("Brand")).ToList(); 

/*Try: 2*/
orderedByPrice = Db.Phones.OrderByProp("Price").ToList();
orderedByBrand = Db.Phones.OrderByProp("Brand").ToList();

/*Try: 3*/
var expressions = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Phone, object>>>
{
    {"Price", (p => p.Price)},
    {"Brand", (p => p.Brand)}
};
orderedByPrice = Db.Phones.OrderBy(expressions["Price"]).ToList();
orderedByBrand = Db.Phones.OrderBy(expressions["Brand"]).ToList();
```